Constructive proofs and terminating algorithms
I was thinking about the following judgement:
¬ ∀n:Nat ¬ϕ(n) ⊢ ∃n:Nat ϕ(n)

I am not sure whether this can be proven constructively, because intuitively, it doesn't look like I can find a 'witness' n such that ϕ(n).
However, we do seem to have an algorithm that can generate witnesses given the premise, because I can simply iterate over the natural numbers and 'check' whether ϕ(n) holds.
I think that my argument is quite informal, but is it the case that just having an algorithm is not enough to have a 'constructive' proof. Is such a situation common?
Ps: I would be curious to know if anything changes the situation for the following:
¬ ∀n:Nat ϕ(n) ⊢ ∃n:Nat ¬ϕ(n)
∀n:Nat ϕ(n) ⊢ ¬ ∃n:Nat ¬ϕ(n)
∀n:Nat ¬ϕ(n) ⊢ ¬ ∃n:Nat ϕ(n)


Congratulations! You've discovered Markov's principle. It is indeed not provable constructively. (Note that you need to require that ϕ be decidable; otherwise this is equivalent to the law of excluded middle.)

@NaïmFavier, Thanks for the comment! I am curious if you can express 'φ is decidable' in the object logic? or is it a metalogical assumption? (This might be off-topic, strictly speaking though..)

Elaborating on my comment:
Since you said you could "check" whether $\phi(n)$ holds, I will assume that $\phi$ is decidable, in the sense that $\forall n : \mathbb{N}. \phi(n) \lor \neg\phi(n)$. Then,

your first ($\neg \forall n : \mathbb{N}. \neg\phi(n) \vdash \exists n : \mathbb{N}. \phi(n)$) and second ($\neg \forall n : \mathbb{N}. \phi(n) \vdash \exists n : \mathbb{N}. \neg\phi(n)$) statements are equivalent to Markov's principle, which is not constructively provable but holds in the effective topos (so you can realise it with, say, Turing machines);
your third ($\forall n : \mathbb{N}. \phi(n) \vdash \neg\exists n : \mathbb{N}. \neg\phi(n)$) and fourth ($\forall n : \mathbb{N}. \neg\phi(n) \vdash \neg\exists n : \mathbb{N}. \phi(n)$) statements are provable constructively.

In fact the third and fourth statements are provable constructively even if you don't assume that $\phi$ is decidable.
